# Set cookie to Post request - Elixir

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

Setting cookie for Get request working perfectly,

But cookie for post request is not happening

```
HTTPoison.post(
  "http://localhost:4000/res",
  body,
  header,
  hackney: [cookie: ["res=a933ec1dd9; logged_in=true"]]
)
```

Comment: Your code works for me on https://requestb.in. I see a header `Cookie: res=a933ec1dd9; logged_in=true` in the request logged there. How are you reading the cookie value in the server?

Comment: Please respect those reading questions from not-so-wide screens and format the code accordingly.

Comment: @Dogbert, You are right, i can read it